# SAP Gateway projects: How to re-anable import functionality of Date Models after project copy?

Tags: sap-gateway

Using t-code SEGW, I created a SAP Gateway project with several data models based on RFC function modules. The data structure is based on the handy "Import" funtionality.

Due to a customer request, I had to copy the project into another, customer owned, namespace.

After the copy, I lost the funtionality to import fields to the data models.
[image: As seen here]

When I create a new entity, the possibility to import is still there. When I copy a fully working project, lets say to $tmp, I lose the import feature again.

Sure, I can still edit my entities by hand but it is tiresome and prone to errors.

So, my question, is there a way to re-enable the import feature of copied SAP Gateway projects?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are importing complete project into customer system, check for the service and model. It should have come if the project has been imported successfully.

Note: Please update SEGW with latest release.